# how to add one form element into another form?

Tags: 6, forms, users

I have a webform. And I want to add some fields of user registration form to the webform because I also want to add the facility of registration on webform submission. So I want to add those fields of user registration form which are required to the webform.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should do it programatically.

Use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to modify form A, load data of form B by [drupal_retrieve_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_retrieve_form/6) inside this function and get fields from form B data which you want to add them to form A

Comment: I will get the form B but then how will add its fields to the form A.

Comment: uupps my fault, try drupal_retrieve_form it gives you form array

Comment: I try this

`$form_user = drupal_retrieve_form('user_register',` `$form_state);`
`$form_user['name']['#weight'] = 2;`
But this could not add the user_register form field 'name'.